# Loop until error 424

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I've been working on this for a couple of hours now, but not able to make it work so far.

I've got some filtered data and I'd like to store the first data cell as a variable to use in loop. However once my loop has deleted all the data and it should end itself I receive an 424 error, object required.

***Code***

```
Sub jjjjj()

Dim rng As Range

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 9).Select

Set rnge = Selection

Do Until (rnge.value = 0)        
    Range("i1").Activate
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete                
Loop

End Sub
```

Error line is `Do Until (rnge = 0)`

I've tried `Do until (rnge.value = "")`

As well as taking out `value`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: how does rnge.Value attain the value of zero?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, I've tried "", that doesn't work either. Basically the code deletes all the data, but then doesn't end because cell the 'ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 9).Select' selects has no data in it.

Comment: first off you declare`rng` and then you `set rnge`  those are different variables and should throw a compile error. Set the `Option Explicit` statement at the top of your code to avoid misspelling variable, this will save you tons of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after something like the code below, explanations inside the code as comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub jjjjj()

Dim FiltRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range, C As Range

' set the filtered range
Set FiltRng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

' loop through areas of Filtered range
For Each Rng In FiltRng.Areas
    ' loop through cells in column "I" of current area
    For Each C In Rng.Columns("I")
        If C.Value = 0 Then Exit Sub ' if value is 0 exit sub
        C.EntireRow.Delete
    Next C
Next Rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, however I recieve an run-time error 13, at ' If C.Value = 0 Then Exit Sub ' if value is 0 exit sub'. I'm still fairly new to vba, therefore not sure how to resolve it.