# Editing the cell value in Specialcells fails?

Tags: vba

I have two sheets, one that information about decks played by players, who owns it, what the deck name is, and earlier names. Then another where I have match information of said player, owner and deck name.

My aim is to update match information deck names to newest. I've these two subprocedures. First finds what we need to update, then uses a filtering subprocedure to filter the match list to only have matches containing the player, owner and deck combination visible.

Then it calls the other method, where I try to update the name. It runs nicely, says happily in the debug log that it has beeen renamed from oldname to new name, but when it's finished, the value in the deck name cell remains unchanged.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I tried out your script, Pefington, and amended the split of for i and for each loops. I also used the Variant approach you suggested. Now it runs again, and says it tries to update 'chulane precon to chulane', but that change is not reflected in the excel sheet.

Had to do an rather ugly way of populating the array of Variants with from the array of Strings.

I also added a rownumber to just check in debugger that it indeed goes through the row with chulane precon, and it does, but still fails to actually save the chulane into the cell. Which is the thing I need help with. :)

```
Sub CleanOldDeckNames()

    ' DISABLE EXCEL ANIMATIONS
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim player As String
    Dim owner As String
    Dim concatenatedOldNames As String
    Dim oldNamesArray() As Variant
    Dim currentName As String
    Dim currentOldName As String
    Dim temporaryOldNameStringArray() As String
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim oldName As Variant
    
    Sheets("Decklist").Select
    Call dl_search_deck_hidden_reset
    
    For i = 12 To 50
        player = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("A" & i).Value
        owner = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("B" & i).Value
        currentName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("C" & i).Value
        concatenatedOldNames = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("D" & i).Value
        
        If Not (StrComp(concatenatedOldNames, "") = 0) Then
            temporaryOldNameStringArray = Split(concatenatedOldNames, ",")
            
            j = 0
            For Each oldNameToBeConverted In temporaryOldNameStringArray
                ReDim Preserve oldNamesArray(j)
                oldNamesArray(j) = CStr(oldNameToBeConverted)
                j = j + 1
            Next oldNameToBeConverted
            
            For Each oldName In oldNamesArray
                currentOldName = Trim(CStr(oldName))
                    
                Sheets("Game Logs").Select
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Game Logs").range("E1:G1").Value = Array(player, owner, currentOldName)
                Call gl_find_rename_deck
                Call RenameInSpecialCells(currentOldName, currentName)
                
            Next oldName
        End If
    Next
            
    Call gl_find_rename_deck_reset
    ' ENABLE EXCEL ANIMATIONS
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub RenameInSpecialCells(oldName As String, currentName As String)
    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Game Logs").AutoFilter.range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If (StrComp(cell, oldName) = 0) Then
            Dim rownumber As Integer
            rownumber = cell.row
            cell = currentName
            Debug.Print ("Renamed " & oldName & " to " & currentName)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I still suspect the actual issue has to do something with the SpecialCells and the way I go through cells with it.

Comment: I'm thinking that I have to change the approach. Like, not that I have found the rownumber, go through all cells in row outside the SpecialCells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit to add after feedback:

```
Sub RenameInSpecialCells(oldName As String, currentName As String)

dim rng as range, c as range

set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Game Logs").AutoFilter.range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) #.range? can't get intellisense to trigger on this one#

For Each c In rng.cells
    If (StrComp(c.value, oldName) = 0) Then
        c.value = currentName
        Debug.Print ("Renamed " & oldName & " to " & currentName)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

First post here, and new at coding, but I think I see some issues and hopefully can help.

```
Dim oldNameS As String
```

Note the `s`, plural.
You then use:

```
For Each oldName In oldNamesArray
```

Now you are calling oldName (singular) as if it was a member of an oldName**s** collection, but it is not.

You could go with:

```
For Each oldNames in oldNamesArray
```

The second problem I think is that you are trying to use a `for each` loop on a `string` array. To do that, your array needs to be a `variant`.

So your array declaration should read:

```
Dim oldNamesArray() as Variant
```

Lastly:

```
Dim name As Variant
```

I don't see this one getting used, maybe lost in the process?

With those comments the code looks like this:

```
Sub CleanOldDeckNames()

    ' DISABLE EXCEL ANIMATIONS
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim player As String
    Dim owner As String
    Dim oldName As String
    Dim oldNamesArray() As Variant
    Dim currentName As String
    Dim currentOldName As String
    
    Sheets("Decklist").Select
    Call dl_search_deck_hidden_reset
    
    For i = 12 To 50
        player = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("A" & i).Value
        owner = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("B" & i).Value
        currentName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("C" & i).Value
        oldName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("D" & i).Value
        oldNamesArray = Split(oldName, ",")
    next

    For Each oldName In oldNamesArray
        currentOldName = Trim(CStr(oldName)) #not sure if CStr required#
            
        Sheets("Game Logs").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Game Logs").range("E1:G1").Value = Array(player, owner, currentOldName)
        Call gl_find_rename_deck
        Call RenameInSpecialCells(currentOldName, currentName)
    Next
            
    Call gl_find_rename_deck_reset
    ' ENABLE EXCEL ANIMATIONS
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub RenameInSpecialCells(oldName As String, currentName As String)
    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Game Logs").AutoFilter.range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If (StrComp(cell, oldName) = 0) Then
            cell = currentName
            Debug.Print ("Renamed " & oldName & " to " & currentName)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Apologies if I'm way off the mark.

Edit to add: Your `for each` in array loop doesn't use `i`, so you can run the `for i` loop and `for each` loop in sequence rather than nesting them. Code amended accordingly.

Comment: Hi Pefingon. Thanks for your input

Comment: Also, I've noticed that sometimes you don't seem to have to declare simple entity types before using the in the `For Each` block. Also names should be correct now, I don't doubt the functionality of the upper method. It works fine. It's the bottom, the actual saving, that doesn't do what I expect it to do.

Comment: Answer amended with an attempt at solving the bottom sub issue. Can't really test, let me know.

Comment: Just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707837/loop-until-error-424) while looking for something else, looks awfully familiar.

Comment: Out of respect, I did not notice your new suggestion before I had posted my own answer. I now tested it out, and it indeed worked, so giving you the credit for the answer anyway.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to circumvent the saving. I could not find any reason for why I could not edit the cell via SpecialCells, so I grabbed the row number and column number and edited it directly in the sheet. Turned out that worked.

I also did not need to use Variant as suggested, this simply works.

```
Sub CleanOldDeckNames()
    ' DISABLE EXCEL ANIMATIONS
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim player As String
    Dim owner As String
    Dim oldNames As String
    Dim oldNamesArray() As String
    Dim currentName As String
    Dim currentOldName As String
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Sheets("Decklist").Select
    Call dl_search_deck_hidden_reset
    
    For i = 12 To 50
        player = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("A" & i).Value
        owner = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("B" & i).Value
        currentName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("C" & i).Value
        oldNames = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Decklist").range("D" & i).Value
        oldNamesArray = Split(oldNames, ",")
            
        Dim name As Variant
        For Each oldName In oldNamesArray
            currentOldName = Trim(oldName)
            
            Sheets("Game Logs").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Game Logs").range("E1:G1").Value = Array(player, owner, currentOldName)
            Call gl_find_rename_deck
            Call RenameInSpecialCells(currentOldName, currentName)
        Next oldName
    Next i
            
    Call gl_find_rename_deck_reset
    ' ENABLE EXCEL ANIMATIONS
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub RenameInSpecialCells(oldName As String, currentName As String)
    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Game Logs").AutoFilter.range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If (StrComp(cell, oldName) = 0) Then
            Debug.Print ("Attemtping to rename: " & cell)
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Game Logs").Cells(cell.row, cell.Column).Value = "Chulane"
            Debug.Print ("New content: " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Game Logs").Cells(cell.row, cell.Column))
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```